# How to apply the configuration (volume mounted) from docker-compose after checking the values in docker container

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm creating test.conf configuration file by using a python script which will be volume mounted to docker-compose.
In python script there are few configuration variable, for which I need to check the values in container and accordingly generate the config.

Python snippet to generate the config file  :

```
dns_ip = os.popen('cat /etc/resolv.conf').read()
dns_match = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)',dns_ip)
try:
        if match:
            dns = dns_match.group(1)
            service_config.append('add service dns_service '+dns+' DNS 53 -healthmonitor NO')
            service_config.append (..... 

            .......

#### Creating config file ######
f = open('test.conf','w')
for i in service_config :       
     f.write(str(i)+"\n")
```

docker-compose file where generated test.conf from above python script will be volume mount:

```
 test-docker:
    image: test
    network_mode: bridge 
    ports:
      - '444:8443'
    privileged: yes
    ulimits:
      core: -1
    volumes:      
      - /test.conf:/config/test.conf
```

Please suggest that how such configuration can be applied after checking the values in container ? Can I pass these details as environment variable, if yes, then how can I achieve it ?

Comment: Can you use an entrypoint wrapper script to create that configuration at container startup time?  (And not a volume or bind mount?)

Comment: Please share any reference?